# jquery - for each applying same height change to all instances

Tags: jquery, foreach

I've the following code to resize images depending upon whether a window height is less than 750px or not. The problem is that while there are several images with the class `.squash`, the script takes the first image, calculates the new height and then applies that height to *all* images with the class `.squash`.  I've also tried without using `.each`, but has the same result.

Would appreciate pointing out where I'm going wrong!  MTIA

```
    $('img.squash').each (

        function() {            

        var oldSquashHeight = $('img.squash').height();
            newSquashHeight = oldSquashHeight * 0.8;

        $('img.squash').css({'height' : newSquashHeight + 'px'});

        }
        )}
```

Comment: keep in mind that some users' browsers aren't maximized and in some cases this could be very annoying

Comment: Thanks Teneff, it's a fluid layout, so hopefully should be okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('img.squash').css({'height' : newSquashHeight + 'px'});
```

should be **changed** to

```
$(this).css({'height' : newSquashHeight + 'px'});
```

and

```
var oldSquashHeight = $('img.squash').height();
```

to

```
var oldSquashHeight = $(this).height();
```

Comment: Many thanks Harish for your speedy help! Will accept your answer after the required 10 mins :-)